# ReferenceError: id is not defined when trying to MapReduce MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've got such a structure in my MongoDB database, collection `transactions_dev`:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4f7aab939e2530cc028552f2"),
   "count": 1,
   "item-id": 2230494020,
   "price": 34.99,
   "seller-id": 16435416,
   "time": "20120403",
   "type": "now" 
}
```

I would like to save it to another collection, where it would be grouped by `seller-id` and `time` (I would like to present daily sales (SUM(price)) of each seller-id).

To do so I wrote this mapreduce:

```
db.runCommand({
mapreduce: "transactions_dev",
map: function() { emit(
    { t: this.time, s: this.seller-id},
    { msum: this.price }
);},
reduce: function(key, vals) {
    var ret = {msum: 0};
    for(var i=0; i< vals.length; i++) {
        ret.msum += vals[i].msum;
    }
    return ret;
},
out: 'result1',
verbose: true
});
```

But I'm getting such exception:

```
"errmsg" : "exception: map invoke failed: JS Error: ReferenceError: id is not defined nofile_b:1",
    "code" : 9014,
```

Does that mean that I have to explicitly define the _id field for the reduced data?

How to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to save it to another collection first?  Why not just aggregate them with a query against this collection?

Comment: btw, your syntax error is because of "-" in the names of your keys.  You will need to use the form this["seller-id"] for all keys that have characters that JS may interpret as operators (or spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using certain characters in your key names ('-' in your case, spaces cause the same problem) you cannot say this.seller-id - it gets parsed as this.seller minus id.  Change your map function to be:

```
function() { emit(
    { t: this.time, s: this["seller-id"]},
    { msum: this.price }
);}
```